# Passing a button select choice back to previous screen

Tags: reactjs, react-native, navigation, pressable

So after some research, I have learned how to make a button that will take the user to another screen, and provide them a text input where they can enter some words, then on pushing the done button take them back to the previous screen where what they typed will be displayed. But for my particular needs, I am trying to figure out how to instead of a text input have a selection of buttons, such as "large, medium, small" and have that button select the data that would be displayed instead, and return them to the previous page where it is displayed.

initial screen

```
function HomeScreen( route ) {
navigation = useNavigation();

React.useEffect(() => {
  if (route.params?.post) {
  }
}, [route.params?.post]);

return (
  <View>
    <Pressable
      title="Create post"
      onPress={() => navigation.navigate('CreatePost')}
    >
      <Text style={{ margin: 10 }}>Post: {route.params?.post}</Text>
    </Pressable
  </View>
);
}
```

button selection screen

```
function CreatePostScreen( route ) {
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  const [postText, setPostText] = React.useState('');

  return (
    <>
      <Pressable
        title="Done"
        onPress={() => {
          navigation.navigate({
            name: 'Home',
            params: { postText },
            merge: true,
          });
        }}
      >
        <Text>
          Large
        </Text>
      </Pressable>
    </>
  );
}
```

any insight is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the data in form of object

```
{post: postText,
 buttonType: 'medium'}
```

For getting the data

```
 React.useEffect(() => {
    if (route.params?.post) {
     var buttonType= route.params?.buttonType
    }
  }, [route.params?.post]);
```

You can store the button type in a variable or state

```
var buttonType = route.params?.buttonType
```

Or You can try with `useState()` hooks

```
const [buttonType, setButtonType]=useState("")
setButtonType(route.params?.buttonType)
```

The for using it just do the following

```
<Text>{buttonType}</Text>
```

Please follow the [React-Documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params)

Comment: Okay that makes sense, but then how do I post that "buttonType" into a <Text></Text> ?

Comment: I have added some reference, Please look into it.